# Bash strings getting cut off when outputting from array at space marks

Tags: arrays, bash, logging, grep, echo

So I am going through a log file and extracting information from said log file such as device name, location, and time of log. It looks something like the following:

```
edge2.mco1-9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT %SEC_LOGIN-5-LOGIN_SUCCESS: Login Success
```

I am coming across an issue where when I run the following:

```
for y in ${DeviceName[@]}
do
    echo "Device: $y"
    counter=1
    for z in ${LocationName[@]}
    do
        testing=($(grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt | cut -f2 -d "-" | cut -f1 -d% | head -n 1))
        if [[ ${testing[$counter]} =~ [^0-9] ]]
        then
            echo $z
            echo $testing
        fi
        
    done
    
done
```

the day number is the only part outputted. DeviceName is an array of device names. LocationName is an array of location names. The complicated part was due to me wanting to only output the location name if it had something coming from the grep since I did not want a long list of locations that had no time attached to it. I did experiment with saving to a .txt file, which did do the correct time, but it seems outputting the correct time is more troublesome due to spaces. Using the example,

```
9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT
```

should be the output. Is there any way to get around this?
The `$testing` is kept as attempts to do `${testing[$counter]}`, `$(${testing[$counter]})`, and other methods did not work giving me errors. Errors are `Jun` and `./finder: line 113: Jun: command not found` respectively $testing at least gives me the day number. Obviously there is an issue with spaces but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I don't know how `counter` in `${testing[counter]}` is set. Perhaps replace by `${testing}`

Comment: You you give an input example with 5-10 lines?

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular .... update the question with *a)* the output from `typeset -p DeviceName LocationName`, *b)* a sample set of input lines from `hacker.txt`  (some that match, some that don't match), *c)* the (wrong) output generated by your script (corresponding to the sample input provided) and *d)* the (correct) expected output (corresponding to the sample input provided)

Comment: The "command not found" error results from trying to use `$(${testing[$counter]})`; that tries to execute the word resulting from the parameter expansion as a command to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ cat hacker.txt
edge2.mco1-9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT %SEC_LOGIN-5-LOGIN_SUCCESS: Login Success
$ y=edge2
$ z=mco1
```

The `grep` command:

```
$ grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt | cut -f2 -d "-" | cut -f1 -d% | head -n 1                                                                    
9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT
```

Loading this into the `testing[]` array:

```
$ testing=( $(grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt | cut -f2 -d "-" | cut -f1 -d% | head -n 1) )
$ typeset -p testing
declare -a testing=([0]="9" [1]="Jun" [2]="11:32:24" [3]="GMT")
```

Running the test:

```
$ counter=1
$ [[ ${testing[$counter]} =~ [^0-9] ]] && echo "success"
success

# turn on debugging to see what we're testing:
$ set -xv                                                  # turn on debugging

$ [[ ${testing[$counter]} =~ [^0-9] ]] && echo "success"
[[ ${testing[$counter]} =~ [^0-9] ]] && echo "success"
+ [[ Jun =~ [^0-9] ]]                                      # contents of testing[1] == 'Jun'
+ echo success
success

$ set +xv                                                  # turn off debugging
```

So far so good.

OP has stated the desired output should look like:

```
9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT
```

But the current `echo` command has an issue:

```
echo $testing
```

`$testing` is an array; without an index `bash` treats `$testing` the same as `${testing[0]}` which in this case outputs `9` (see the output from `typeset -p testing` - above); to output the entire contents of the array OP can use:

```
$ echo "${testing[@]}"
9 Jun 11:32:24 GMT
```

Net result: OP should be able to change `echo $testing` to `echo "${testing[@]}"` to obtain the desired output.

---

OP has mentioned the code complication (loading `testing[]` array, comparing `testing[1]` ???) is due to only printing output if `grep` finds a match.

We can streamline the code a bit by replacing the guts of the `for z` loop with:

```
    # no need for array, just capture datetime stamp:

    dtstamp=$(grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt | cut -f2 -d "-" | cut -f1 -d% | head -n 1)

    # is length of 'dtstamp' non-zero?

    if [[ -n "${dtstamp}" ]]
    then
        echo "${z}"
        echo "${dtstamp}"
    fi
```

If the objective is to only print `${z}` when `grep` finds a match (ie, OP doesn't need to print `${dtstamp}`) we can streamline the code a bit more to where the only command in the `for z` loop is:

```
grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt >/dev/null && echo "${z}"
```

Demo:

```
$ z=mco1
$ grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt >/dev/null && echo "${z}"
mco1

$ z=xxxx
$ grep "$y\.$z\-.*\%" hacker.txt >/dev/null && echo "${z}"
              <<<=== no output
```

**NOTES:**

- can also remove the `counter=1` from the current code
- OP should consider cutting-n-pasting their code (along with the appropriate shebang, eg, `#!/bin/bash`) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/); this will report on syntax issues as well as make some suggestions re: 'best practices'

Comment: Huh. I can't believe I forgot to use @ for the array. Maybe the complicated way I was trying to print z was throwing me off. Thanks for the help!